# Bootstrap Modal open on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap modal popup to show content in popup and I'm using if/else condition to open modal popup. I don't want to open modal popup when condition is false. My code:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size: 10px" href="#" data-target="#myModal" title="Edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Edit</a>
```

My jQuery is:

```
 $('a[data-target=#myModal]').on('click', function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        if (filters.length <= 0) {
            alert('Please select any one item in grid');
        }
        else {
            $(this).attr('href', '/GeoRegion/Edit/' + filters[0]);
            var target = $(this).attr("href");

            // load the url and show modal on success
            $("#myModal").load(target, function () {
                $("#myModal").modal("show");
            });
        }
    });
```

If filters.length<=0 then I don't want to open popup. Now popup opening with empty content.

Comment: run `console.log(filters)` after `ev.preventDefault()` and show us what the output is

Comment: Hi Andrew, filters is just a array. If array length is 0 then i dont want to display modal popup. Am getting alert message but modal popup also opening

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that you have `data-toggle="modal"` on your button, which is the data-attributes (HTML5) way of using modals. this will work without any javascript written.

remove `data-toggle` and then your javascript should run correctly.

[documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Answer (score 7):

Try to do:

```
if (filters.length <= 0) {
    $("#myModal").modal("hide");
}
```

Comment: Hi Felix, still modal pop opening with empty content

Comment: What's `filters`? Can you create a fiddle to replicate your problem. I'll try to help you.

Comment: Hi Felix, filters is just a array. If array length is 0 then i dont want to display modal popup

Answer (score 1):

```
//insert this code in your condition.
//for example.
    
if(...){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
 }
```